# Create JSON using WSO2 ESB Script mediator

Tags: javascript, json, wso2, esb, payload

I have used WSO2 ESB script mediator to generate JSON.
Tried to get following JSON Object.

```
var payLoad = {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "typeId": typeId,
    "userId": userId,
    "riskId": riskId
};
mc.setPayloadJSON(payLoad)
```

But return following JSON from ESB

```
{
    "id": "305",
    "riskId": "254",
    "typeId": "1",
    "userId": "1",
    "name": "goal"
}
```

How can i correct order.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
     <property name="id" expression="json-eval($.id)"></property>
     <property name="name" expression="json-eval($.name)"></property>
     <property name="typeId" expression="json-eval($.typeId)"></property>
     <property name="userId" expression="json-eval($.userId)"></property>
     <property name="riskId" expression="json-eval($.riskId)"></property>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
        {
        "id":"$1",
        "name":"$2",
        "typeId":"$3",
        "userId":"$4",
        "riskId":"$5"
        }
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.id"></arg>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.name"></arg>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.typeId"></arg>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.userId"></arg>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.riskId"></arg>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But if id is integer then it should be integer instead of string 
(in double quotes)

Comment: Yes, String values only have to be encapsulated by double quotes.

Comment: I used script mediator to achieve this but crashed if json object is very large in size